# javascript in ascx page throwing HTTPexception

Tags: javascript, asp.net, validation, httpexception

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function ValidateProductID(sender, args)
{
    var productID = document.getElementById('<%=txtProductID.ClientID%>').value;
    var productType = document.getElementById('<%=rcbProduct.ClientID%>').value;
    if (productID != "" && productType == "") {
        args.IsValid = false;
    }
    else
        args.IsValid = true;
}
```

this script for the custom validator is throwing exception .

`An exception of type 'System.Web.HttpException' occurred in System.Web.dll but was not handled in user code Additional information: The Controls collection cannot be modified because the control contains code blocks (i.e. <% ... %>)`.

can someone tell me how to fix it.

Comment: it seems getElementById('<%=txtProductID.ClientID%>') is throwing the exception. is there any other way in javascript to obtain control value??

Comment: document.getElementById('txtProductID').value is not working either

Answer (score 2):

Add  `ClientIDMode="Static"` to those textboxes (or whatever they are) and just use `document.getElementById('txtProductID').value;`

[Per the docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.clientidmode%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), setting the `ClientIDMode` to `Static` means:

> The ClientID value is set to the value of the ID property.

That means the ID won't be changed by some algorithm and will be `txtProductID` instead of something that you have to access with `txtProductID.ClientID`.

Usually the error you are getting is because you put that script inside of some other control with `runat="server"` on it. The solution above is likely your easiest solution, though without more of your code it is hard to say.

Comment: This won't work on older versions of the .Net framework.

Comment: Possibly, but still worth noting that ClientIDMode isn't always available. +1 for providing multiple solutions.

Comment: @RandomWebGuy True, but usually if the OP is using an old version of ASP.NET (< 4.0) they will mention that. My answer provides another solution as well (moving the script), though I'm comfortable with solutions that work with the related technology going back 5 years (ASP.NET 4.0 release :). Though yes, your comment is worth noting, as you say.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, I had my script out of the Content Template, moved it in with the existing code and it works !